# Javafx: How to fix drag and drop interferring with Dialog

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, paste

In my application, the user can drag some custom format from some list into a `GridPane`. There is also some additional information I need from the user in some special cases, so I need to open a `TextInputDialog`. A (strongly) simplified version of the code looks like that:

```
setOnDragDropped(event -> {
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    // ... handle object in DragBoard
    event.setDropCompleted(true);
    event.consume();
    String text = new TextInputDialog().showAndWait().get();
}
```

Retrieving the value the user entered is no problem, but the strange thing I noticed is that the user is unable to paste text into the `TextInputDialog`. Neither by pressing Strg+V, nor by using right click -> paste (the option is greyed out). This might sound like a small problem, but in this usecase the user will want to paste text quite often.

This only happens when I put custom data into the `ClipboardContent`, but **not** when I just put a `String` there. This even seems to be the case when the Dialog is called inside `setOnDragDone(...)`.

So is there a way to open that `TextInputDialog` in response to the drag event and still be able to paste text?

This is a complete application which reproduces this problem:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DataFormat;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        DataFormat format = new DataFormat("some format");
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        Label dragMeLabel = new Label("drag me");
        Label dropHereLabel = new Label("drop here");
        dragMeLabel.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            Dragboard db = dragMeLabel.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
            ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
            cc.put(format, "foo bar");
            db.setContent(cc);
        });
        dropHereLabel.setOnDragOver(event -> event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY));
        dropHereLabel.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
            event.setDropCompleted(true);
            event.consume();
            String text = new TextInputDialog().showAndWait().get();
            //can't past text into this Dialog
        });
        pane.add(dragMeLabel, 0, 0);
        pane.add(dropHereLabel, 1, 0);

        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setVgap(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 200, 50));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: That was actually a valuable request, as I managed to further specify the problem. It only happens, when I put some custom `DataFormat` into the `Dragbord`..

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a bug. I can't seem to figure a workaround: even saving string data from the system clipboard and manually reinserting it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another thread within `setOnDragDropped`, let this method complete and show the dialog with `Platform.runLater`.
In the end, there will be something like this:

```java
BooleanProperty dialogTrigger = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
dropHereLabel.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
  event.setDropCompleted(true);
  event.consume();
  new Thread(() -> dialogTrigger.set(true)).start();
});
dialogTrigger.addListener(
  (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
      Platform.runLater(() -> new TextInputDialog().showAndWait();
    }
    dialogTrigger.set(false);
});
```

After that pasting any strings into the dialog will be possible.